# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED node.js https.get request

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, get

I'm running the following in a small test node project.

```
var https = require('https');

var request = https.get('https://example.com/script.json', function(response){
    console.dir(response);
});

request.on('error', function(){
    console.log(err);
});
```

When I try to console.dir the response I get the following error.

```
throw er; // Unhandles 'error' event
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxx
```

It's a simple get request to a json file on an external server. I know the file exists so I'm not sure why I'm getting the above error. The file can be run in the browser and requires no authentication.

**UPDATE**: I edited the code. created a promise and added an `.on('error'...` to catch any issues.

The following is now output:

```
( [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxx]
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
  port: 443 )
```

Comment: Are you sure your browser isn't serving you a cached version? Are you using some sort of firewall that prevents may prevent "unauthorized" applications from making network connections?

Comment: @robertklep - yes I am behind a proxy. I have the details (port etc). As you suggest this could be causing the issue. I already have `npm config set proxy http` and `npm config set proxy https` set up. But is this error caused by something different to that?

Comment: If you're behind a proxy, take a look at [`request`](https://github.com/request/request#proxies), which makes dealing with proxy servers a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to help from @robertklep I came up with the following solution which allows me to connect to HTTPS from behind a proxy using request

```
const https = require('https');
const request = require('request');

request(
    {
    'url':'https://https://example.com/script.json',
    'proxy':'http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx'
    },
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body);
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The other server is not up, or not listening to 443 port so you get a connection refused.
Another option is that the nodejs app is resolving that example url differently to a different ip than your pc.

Comment: ok, so apart from trying another port, how would I fix the second possible issue you suggested.

Comment: use direct ip in your testing, update hosts file on the machine, so on....

Comment: thanks - but that's not really making much sense to me. just started out with nodejs